# unable to get sum using distinct loop sum xslt

Tags: xslt-3.0

I am new to xslt. I am creating a transform and need to calculate tax amount based on tax rate. The input file contains different tax rates and tax amount. The requirement is to look for common tax rates, take individual tax amount and sum them all. This creates a single `T` element.

If there are multiple tax rates, group common tax amounts and total them and form `T` element.

For example: Input file is:

```
<DATA>
    <LIST_G_TRX>
        <G_TRX>
            <LIST_G_HEADER>
                <G_HEADER>
                    <COUNTRYCODE>500</COUNTRYCODE>
                    <INVOICENUMBER>55005</INVOICENUMBER>
                    <CUSTOMER_TRX_ID>182066</CUSTOMER_TRX_ID>
                    <CUSTOMERID>5002013</CUSTOMERID>
                    <CUSTOMERORDERNUMBER>001</CUSTOMERORDERNUMBER>
                    <ORDERDATE>2019-01-09T00:00:00.000+00:00</ORDERDATE>
                    <INVOICEDATE>2019-01-09</INVOICEDATE>
                    <BILLTOCONTACT>XXXLutz Logistik AG</BILLTOCONTACT>
                    <BILLTONAME>XXXLutz Logistik AG</BILLTONAME>
                    <BILLTOADDRESS1>Römerstraße 999</BILLTOADDRESS1>
                    <BILLTOADDRESS2/>
                    <BILLTOADDRESS3/>
                    <BILLTOCITY>Wels</BILLTOCITY>
                    <BILLTOPOSTALCODE>4600</BILLTOPOSTALCODE>
                    <BILLTOCOUNTRYCODE>AT</BILLTOCOUNTRYCODE>
                    <CONTACTPHONENUMBER>11111111</CONTACTPHONENUMBER>
                    <CONTACTPHONEEXT/>
                    <CURRENCY>EUR</CURRENCY>
                    <CUSTOMERTAXID>ATU64784111</CUSTOMERTAXID>
                    <ODTAXID>FN 150931</ODTAXID>
                    <INVOICETYPE>R</INVOICETYPE>
                    <TOTALINVOICEVALUE>124.8</TOTALINVOICEVALUE>
                    <TOTALTAXABLEAMOUNT>104</TOTALTAXABLEAMOUNT>
                    <TOTALTAX>20.80</TOTALTAX>
                    <TOTALMISCCHARGE>0.00</TOTALMISCCHARGE>
                    <TOTALDETAILPRICE/>
                    <PAYERCUSTOMERID>5002013</PAYERCUSTOMERID>
                    <PAYERCONTACT>XXXLutz Logistik AG</PAYERCONTACT>
                    <PAYERNAME>XXXLutz Logistik AG</PAYERNAME>
                    <PAYERADDRESS1>Filialnummer ZL</PAYERADDRESS1>
                    <PAYERADDRESS2>Gewerbestrasse 29</PAYERADDRESS2>
                    <PAYERADDRESS3/>
                    <PAYERCITY>Sattledt</PAYERCITY>
                    <PAYERPOSTALCODE>4642</PAYERPOSTALCODE>
                    <PAYERCOUNTRY>AT</PAYERCOUNTRY>
                    <PAYERPHONENUMBER>22222222</PAYERPHONENUMBER>
                    <PAYERPHONEEXT/>
                    <SOLDTOCUSTOMERID>5002013</SOLDTOCUSTOMERID>
                    <SOLDTONAME>XXXLutz Logistik AG</SOLDTONAME>
                    <SOLDTOADDRESS1>Filialnummer ZL</SOLDTOADDRESS1>
                    <SOLDTOADDRESS2>Gewerbestrasse 29</SOLDTOADDRESS2>
                    <SOLDTOADDRESS3/>
                    <SOLDTOCITY>Sattledt</SOLDTOCITY>
                    <SOLDTOPOSTALCODE>4642</SOLDTOPOSTALCODE>
                    <SOLDTOCOUNTRY>AT</SOLDTOCOUNTRY>
                    <SOLDTOPHONENUMBER>22222222</SOLDTOPHONENUMBER>
                    <SOLDTOPHONEEXT/>
                    <SUPPLIERNAME>Viking Direkt GesmbH</SUPPLIERNAME>
                    <SUPPLIERADDRESS1>Tragweiner Str. 57</SUPPLIERADDRESS1>
                    <SUPPLIERADDRESS2/>
                    <SUPPLIERADDRESS3/>
                    <SUPPLIERCITY>Pregarten</SUPPLIERCITY>
                    <SUPPLIERPOSTALCODE>4230</SUPPLIERPOSTALCODE>
                    <SUPPLIERCOUNTRY>AT</SUPPLIERCOUNTRY>
                    <SUPPLIERPHONENUMBER/>
                    <SUPPLIERPHONEEXT/>
                    <REFERENCEINVOICENUMBER/>
                    <CREDITCARDNUMBER/>
                    <EMAILADDRESS/>
                    <DUEDATE>2019-01-14T00:00:00.000+00:00</DUEDATE>
                    <CREDITNOTEREASON/>
                    <LAST_PRINTED_DATE>2019-01-10T12:47:28.000+00:00</LAST_PRINTED_DATE>
                    <FIRST_PRINT_DATE>2019-01-10T12:47:28.000+00:00</FIRST_PRINT_DATE>
                    <PRINTING_COUNT>1</PRINTING_COUNT>
                    <TRANSACTION_SOURCE>Distributed Order Orchestration</TRANSACTION_SOURCE>
                    <LIST_G_LINES>
                        <G_LINES>
                            <CUSTOMER_TRX_ID>182066</CUSTOMER_TRX_ID>
                            <COUNTRYCODE>500</COUNTRYCODE>
                            <CUSTOMERID>5002013</CUSTOMERID>
                            <CUSTOMERORDERNUMBER>001</CUSTOMERORDERNUMBER>
                            <DELIVERYNOTENUMBER/>
                            <DELIVERYNOTELINENUMBER/>
                            <DELIVERYDATE>2019-01-09T00:00:00.000+00:00</DELIVERYDATE>
                            <INVOICELINENUMBER>2</INVOICELINENUMBER>
                            <ITEMNUMBER>6873291</ITEMNUMBER>
                            <INVOICEDQUANTITY>1</INVOICEDQUANTITY>
                            <PRICE>-20</PRICE>
                            <LINEAMOUNT>-20.00</LINEAMOUNT>
                            <ORDERNUMBER>840</ORDERNUMBER>
                            <UNITOFMEASURE>EA</UNITOFMEASURE>
                            <INVOICENUMBER>55005</INVOICENUMBER>
                            <TAXRATE/>
                            <TAXAMOUNT/>
                            <TAXCODE/>
                            <ITEMDESCRIPTION/>
                            <SHIPTOCONTACT/>
                            <SHIPTONAME>XXXLutz Logistik AG</SHIPTONAME>
                            <SHIPTOADDRESS1>Filialnummer ZL</SHIPTOADDRESS1>
                            <SHIPTOADDRESS2>Gewerbestrasse 29</SHIPTOADDRESS2>
                            <SHIPTOADDRESS3/>
                            <SHIPTOCITY>Sattledt</SHIPTOCITY>
                            <SHIPTOPOSTALCODE>4642</SHIPTOPOSTALCODE>
                            <SHIPTOCOUNTRY>AT</SHIPTOCOUNTRY>
                            <CONTACTPHONENUMBER>22222222</CONTACTPHONENUMBER>
                            <CONTACTPHONEEXT/>
                            <ORDERTYPE>R</ORDERTYPE>
                            <ORDERLINENUMBER>1</ORDERLINENUMBER>
                            <ORDERDATE>2019-01-09</ORDERDATE>
                            <CUSTOMERITEMDESCRIPTION/>
                            <INVOICELINECOMMENT1/>
                            <INVOICELINECOMMENT2/>
                            <TRANSACTIONID/>
                            <CUSTOMERCOSTCENTER/>
                            <CUSTOMERITEMNUMBER/>
                            <CUSTOMERORDERLINENUMBER/>
                            <ORDEREDQTY>1</ORDEREDQTY>
                            <SHIPPEDQTY>1</SHIPPEDQTY>
                        </G_LINES>
                        <G_LINES>
                            <CUSTOMER_TRX_ID>182066</CUSTOMER_TRX_ID>
                            <COUNTRYCODE>500</COUNTRYCODE>
                            <CUSTOMERID>5002013</CUSTOMERID>
                            <CUSTOMERORDERNUMBER>001</CUSTOMERORDERNUMBER>
                            <DELIVERYNOTENUMBER/>
                            <DELIVERYNOTELINENUMBER/>
                            <DELIVERYDATE/>
                            <INVOICELINENUMBER/>
                            <ITEMNUMBER/>
                            <INVOICEDQUANTITY/>
                            <PRICE/>
                            <LINEAMOUNT/>
                            <ORDERNUMBER/>
                            <UNITOFMEASURE/>
                            <INVOICENUMBER>55005</INVOICENUMBER>
                            <TAXRATE>20</TAXRATE>
                            <TAXAMOUNT>24.80</TAXAMOUNT>
                            <TAXCODE/>
                            <ITEMDESCRIPTION>HP 7612 e-All-in-One-GroAformatdrucker</ITEMDESCRIPTION>
                            <SHIPTOCONTACT/>
                            <SHIPTONAME/>
                            <SHIPTOADDRESS1/>
                            <SHIPTOADDRESS2/>
                            <SHIPTOADDRESS3/>
                            <SHIPTOCITY/>
                            <SHIPTOPOSTALCODE/>
                            <SHIPTOCOUNTRY/>
                            <CONTACTPHONENUMBER/>
                            <CONTACTPHONEEXT/>
                            <ORDERTYPE>R</ORDERTYPE>
                            <ORDERLINENUMBER/>
                            <ORDERDATE/>
                            <CUSTOMERITEMDESCRIPTION/>
                            <INVOICELINECOMMENT1/>
                            <INVOICELINECOMMENT2/>
                            <TRANSACTIONID/>
                            <CUSTOMERCOSTCENTER/>
                            <CUSTOMERITEMNUMBER/>
                            <CUSTOMERORDERLINENUMBER/>
                            <ORDEREDQTY/>
                            <SHIPPEDQTY/>
                        </G_LINES>
                        <G_LINES>
                            <CUSTOMER_TRX_ID>182066</CUSTOMER_TRX_ID>
                            <COUNTRYCODE>500</COUNTRYCODE>
                            <CUSTOMERID>5002013</CUSTOMERID>
                            <CUSTOMERORDERNUMBER>001</CUSTOMERORDERNUMBER>
                            <DELIVERYNOTENUMBER/>
                            <DELIVERYNOTELINENUMBER/>
                            <DELIVERYDATE/>
                            <INVOICELINENUMBER/>
                            <ITEMNUMBER/>
                            <INVOICEDQUANTITY/>
                            <PRICE/>
                            <LINEAMOUNT/>
                            <ORDERNUMBER/>
                            <UNITOFMEASURE/>
                            <INVOICENUMBER>55005</INVOICENUMBER>
                            <TAXRATE>20</TAXRATE>
                            <TAXAMOUNT>-4.00</TAXAMOUNT>
                            <TAXCODE/>
                            <ITEMDESCRIPTION>HP</ITEMDESCRIPTION>
                            <SHIPTOCONTACT/>
                            <SHIPTONAME/>
                            <SHIPTOADDRESS1/>
                            <SHIPTOADDRESS2/>
                            <SHIPTOADDRESS3/>
                            <SHIPTOCITY/>
                            <SHIPTOPOSTALCODE/>
                            <SHIPTOCOUNTRY/>
                            <CONTACTPHONENUMBER/>
                            <CONTACTPHONEEXT/>
                            <ORDERTYPE>R</ORDERTYPE>
                            <ORDERLINENUMBER/>
                            <ORDERDATE/>
                            <CUSTOMERITEMDESCRIPTION/>
                            <INVOICELINECOMMENT1/>
                            <INVOICELINECOMMENT2/>
                            <TRANSACTIONID/>
                            <CUSTOMERCOSTCENTER/>
                            <CUSTOMERITEMNUMBER/>
                            <CUSTOMERORDERLINENUMBER/>
                            <ORDEREDQTY/>
                            <SHIPPEDQTY/>
                        </G_LINES>
                        <G_LINES>
                            <CUSTOMER_TRX_ID>182066</CUSTOMER_TRX_ID>
                            <COUNTRYCODE>500</COUNTRYCODE>
                            <CUSTOMERID>5002013</CUSTOMERID>
                            <CUSTOMERORDERNUMBER>001</CUSTOMERORDERNUMBER>
                            <DELIVERYNOTENUMBER/>
                            <DELIVERYNOTELINENUMBER/>
                            <DELIVERYDATE>2019-01-09T00:00:00.000+00:00</DELIVERYDATE>
                            <INVOICELINENUMBER>1</INVOICELINENUMBER>
                            <ITEMNUMBER>6873291</ITEMNUMBER>
                            <INVOICEDQUANTITY>1</INVOICEDQUANTITY>
                            <PRICE>124</PRICE>
                            <LINEAMOUNT>124.00</LINEAMOUNT>
                            <ORDERNUMBER>840</ORDERNUMBER>
                            <UNITOFMEASURE>EA</UNITOFMEASURE>
                            <INVOICENUMBER>55005</INVOICENUMBER>
                            <TAXRATE/>
                            <TAXAMOUNT/>
                            <TAXCODE/>
                            <ITEMDESCRIPTION/>
                            <SHIPTOCONTACT/>
                            <SHIPTONAME>XXXLutz Logistik AG</SHIPTONAME>
                            <SHIPTOADDRESS1>Filialnummer ZL</SHIPTOADDRESS1>
                            <SHIPTOADDRESS2>Gewerbestrasse 29</SHIPTOADDRESS2>
                            <SHIPTOADDRESS3/>
                            <SHIPTOCITY>Sattledt</SHIPTOCITY>
                            <SHIPTOPOSTALCODE>4642</SHIPTOPOSTALCODE>
                            <SHIPTOCOUNTRY>AT</SHIPTOCOUNTRY>
                            <CONTACTPHONENUMBER>22222222</CONTACTPHONENUMBER>
                            <CONTACTPHONEEXT/>
                            <ORDERTYPE>R</ORDERTYPE>
                            <ORDERLINENUMBER>1</ORDERLINENUMBER>
                            <ORDERDATE>2019-01-09</ORDERDATE>
                            <CUSTOMERITEMDESCRIPTION/>
                            <INVOICELINECOMMENT1/>
                            <INVOICELINECOMMENT2/>
                            <TRANSACTIONID/>
                            <CUSTOMERCOSTCENTER/>
                            <CUSTOMERITEMNUMBER/>
                            <CUSTOMERORDERLINENUMBER/>
                            <ORDEREDQTY>1</ORDEREDQTY>
                            <SHIPPEDQTY>1</SHIPPEDQTY>
                        </G_LINES>
                    </LIST_G_LINES>
```

My output should be similar to this:

```
<H>
<tax rate 20>
<tax amount 102.60>
</H>
<H>
<tax rate 7>
<tax amount 21.50>
</H>
<H>
<tax rate 19>
<tax amount 13.28>
</H>
```

My xslt is:

```
<xsl:variable name="vTaxRateCount" select="count(distinct-values(LIST_G_LINES/G_LINES/TAXRATE))"/>
                    <xsl:variable name="vDistinct">
                <xsl:for-each select="fn:distinct-values(LIST_G_LINES/G_LINES/TAXRATE)">
                            <xsl:element name="Values">
                                <xsl:value-of select="."/>
                            </xsl:element>
                        </xsl:for-each>
                    </xsl:variable>
                    <xsl:variable name="vPath" select="LIST_G_LINES/G_LINES/TAXAMOUNT"/>
                    <xsl:for-each select="$vDistinct/Values">
                    <xsl:variable name="vUniqueVal" select="."/>
                        <xsl:for-each select="LIST_G_LINES/G_LINES/TAXRATE=.">
                            <xsl:element name="TaxAmount">
                                <xsl:value-of select="sum($vPath[@TAXRATE = $vUniqueVal])"/>
                                <xsl:value-of select="$vUniqueVal"/>
                            </xsl:element>
                        </xsl:for-each>
                    </xsl:for-each>
```

This code doesn't seem to work. Could you please help.

Comment: Is your input file an XML file ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your input and given XSLT, assuming the input file as below: (if it is **XML**)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<LIST_G_LINES>
  <G_LINES>
    <Taxrates> 20 <Taxamount> 1.60 </Taxamount></Taxrates>
  </G_LINES>
  <G_LINES>
    <Taxrates> 7 <Taxamount> 21.50 </Taxamount></Taxrates>
  </G_LINES>
  <G_LINES>
    <Taxrates> 19 <Taxamount> 1.60 </Taxamount></Taxrates>
  </G_LINES>
  <G_LINES>
    <Taxrates> 19 <Taxamount> 11.68 </Taxamount></Taxrates>
  </G_LINES>
  <G_LINES>
    <Taxrates> 20 <Taxamount> 101 </Taxamount></Taxrates>
  </G_LINES>
</LIST_G_LINES>
```

An XSLT 2.0 solution can be as following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
exclude-result-prefixes="xs">

<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />

<xsl:template match="/LIST_G_LINES">
    <xsl:for-each-group select="G_LINES" group-by="Taxrates/text()">
        <H>
            <TaxRate>
                <xsl:value-of select="current-grouping-key()" />
            </TaxRate>
            <TaxAmount>
                <xsl:value-of select="sum(current-group()/Taxrates/Taxamount)" />
            </TaxAmount>
        </H>
    </xsl:for-each-group>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Refer [here](http://xsltransform.net/3MP2uBN/1) to see the output

**Edit:** Based on your updated **XML**, you can try the following **XSLT 3.0** solution:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:math="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions/math"
exclude-result-prefixes="xs math" version="3.0">

<xsl:mode streamable="yes" />
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />

<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:for-each-group select="DATA/LIST_G_TRX/G_TRX/LIST_G_HEADER/G_HEADER/LIST_G_LINES/G_LINES" composite="yes" group-by="TAXRATE">
        <xsl:if test="current-grouping-key() != ''">
            <H>
                <TaxRate>
                    <xsl:value-of select="current-grouping-key()" />
                </TaxRate>
                <TaxAmount>
                    <xsl:value-of select="sum(current-group()/TAXAMOUNT)" />
                </TaxAmount>
            </H>
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:for-each-group>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the help. Yes the input file is an xml file. The output required should be a child element and using template match doesnt not work. Required output should contain Parent H element followed by D element and T element which is the result of common tax rate. <H> can have multiple D's and all common tax rates results in T. Please advise. Thanks.

Comment: It can be because of structure hierarchy or any namespace being there in your input. Can you provide a minimal input ? Meanwhile, try replacing this line `<xsl:template match="//LIST_G_LINES">` (with double slash)

Comment: my input looks like: <LIST_G_LINES>
  <G_LINES>
    <Taxrates> 20 <Taxamount> 1.60 </Taxamount></Taxrates>
  </G_LINES>
  <G_LINES>
    <Taxrates> 7 <Taxamount> 21.50 </Taxamount></Taxrates>
  </G_LINES>
  <G_LINES>
    <Taxrates> 19 <Taxamount> 1.60 </Taxamount></Taxrates>
  </G_LINES>
  <G_LINES>
    <Taxrates> 19 <Taxamount> 11.68 </Taxamount></Taxrates>
  </G_LINES>
  <G_LINES>
    <Taxrates> 20 <Taxamount> 101 </Taxamount></Taxrates>
  </G_LINES>
</LIST_G_LINES>

Comment: Please update your question with the required structure of output. Don't put the code in comments.

Comment: Adding // produces same error about child of element not allowed. Am using XSLT 3.0 version.

Comment: I have updated my question with input file. Thank you again for your help.

Comment: XSL transformation failed
 Unexpected element <xsl:template>
  Error location: xsl:stylesheet / xsl:template / xsl:for-each / xsl:element / xsl:element / xsl:template
  Details
   XTSE0010: Element <xsl:template> is not allowed as child of element <xsl:element>

Comment: Highlighted line: <xsl:template match="//LIST_G_LINES"> during the error.

Comment: Okay. I have updated it in my answer. Please check if it is working at your end or not.

Comment: Perfect. It works. Thank you so much for your help Vebbie.

Comment: Your Welcome! You can accept the answer if it is working for you. So that others can find it easily when they have similar problem as yours.

Comment: I don't think that code would be streamable, not sure why you put the `streamable="yes"` for the `xsl:mode` in there. That way a processor supporting streaming like Saxon EE would reject your code as it is not streamable. Also the `composite="yes"` is not necessary and kind of confusing as it seems the `G_LINES` items in the grouping population only have a single `TAXRATE` child.

Comment: @MartinHonnen : Thank you for correcting. Regarding composite attribute, I initially tried to combine ‘customer_trx_id’ with taxrate (to verify if it’s working with multiple keys). I ll optimise the code accordingly.